# Bellman ford vs Dijikstra?

Tags: data-structures, dijkstra, bellman-ford

After reading Dijkstra and Bellman-ford I have one doubt that why Dijkstra give the answer in one iteration while bellman ford take n-1 iteration ?

Comment: Did you read the comments on the tags? The answer is there already.

Comment: due to negative edge?

Comment: Correct. Consider that a negative edge may have a value of minus one billion, larger than all the positive weights together. Until you've checked all edges, you don't know what the largest negative node is, and how it would affect your outcome.

Comment: Bellman-Ford exploits the fact that a simple path from an arbitrary vertex `i` to an arbitrary vertex `j` in the graph can take a maximum of `n-1` hops where `n` is the total number of vertices in the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i have new id i can not comment . Here is something to read which might help you.

While doing on paper you might be assuming the best order for bellman-ford that why you got the confusion.

Remember that the  algorithm bellman ford works no matter in which order the edges are processed .Now try to rethink different order you will see that in worst case it will be n-1.

In fact this is the reason why you have to do n-1 iterations. If you would know, what is the best order of edges - only one iteration would be enough.

Here is a link which might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/41772030/13265840

Hope this might help you !!!